# Auth0 How to see users role in react frontend

Tags: reactjs, roles, auth0

I would like to see which role a user has, to then show things in react only if a certain role is enabled for that user.

Like this

```
if (user.role1) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>The role 1 is enabled</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
};
```

I tried with the management API to get roles, but that doesn’t work. It is not good to call API management from single page applications either. I tried to add roles to the metadata, but I don’t know how to access those roles. How can I access the roles within the meta data?

Comment: How did you integrate Auth0 into the React app? Are you using a specific library? For your application, are you using a"Single Page Web Application" or the "Regular Web Application" configuration?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: To sync the role to the FE, you need to put it in the JWT, you can do it with this guide
https://io.permit.io/auth0-integration

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED
i added a rule in the auth0 library like this

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const namespace = 'https://myroles.com';
  if (event.authorization) {
    api.idToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/roles`, event.authorization.roles);
    api.accessToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/roles`, event.authorization.roles);
  }
}
```

then in react you can view it in the user from useAuth0() hook:

```
import './App.css';
import './Loader.css';
import React, {  } from 'react';
import LoginButton from './Components/Login/Login';
import LogoutButton from './Components/Login/Logout';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import MainHeader from './Components/MainHeader/MainHeader';
 

function App() {

  const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <br/>
        <div className="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  } 
  else if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MainHeader />
        <h1>Please login!</h1>
        <LoginButton />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  } 
  else if (isAuthenticated) {
    // <GetRole id={user.sub}/>
    // GetRoleP(user.sub);
    const roles = user['https://myroles.com/roles'];
    let nsIsEnabled = roles.includes('nos-security');

    if (nsIsEnabled){
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <MainHeader />
          <h1>Welcome {user.name}</h1>
          <h1>Nos security enabled</h1>
          <LogoutButton />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <MainHeader />
          <h1>Welcome {user.name}</h1>
          <LogoutButton />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    };
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I keep seeing this as a solution, and I feel like this is what I want.  Where I am lost, is the `exports.onExecutePostLogin` code.  Where does this go?  in the `/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts` file?